# Android: How to get value from LiveData without Observing it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

> Blockquote

I have separate classes in which I handle data fetching (Using Room) and I usually return LiveData  list of objects from it and update them. Now I have a settings class where when i press "Backup", i want to have the returned data stored in a ViewModel, but the problem is that in order to get the value, I need to observe the LiveData list of objects. I do not want to observe it since i just need the value (list of objects) to perform the backup. 
I've tried the below method:

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM $DATABASE_TABLE_GOAL")
suspend fun getAllGoals_NotLive(): List<Goal>
```

ViewModel

```
var goals_NotLive: List<Goal> = ArrayList()

fun getGoalsNotLive(){
    _uiScope.launch {

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            goals_NotLive = database.goalDao.getAllGoals_NotLive()
        }
    }
}
```

Activity

```
fun getGoals(): List<Goal>{
    _viewModel.getGoalsNotLive()
    return _viewModel.goals_NotLive
}
```

But it stills return Size 0. What should I do?

Comment: If `getValue()` returns `null`, your `LiveData` does not have any data yet. Add another method on your DAO that implements a blocking call, then use that for your backup stuff (from a background thread).

Comment: Can you share some code as an answer please ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right now, you have a DAO that has a function like this:

```
@Query("...")
fun gimmeData(): LiveData<SomethingOrAnother>
```

That requires you to observe the `LiveData` in order to have your query be executed. In your case, you do not want that for some scenarios. So, you need another function.

One option is to have a synchronous version of the function:

```
@Query("...")
fun gimmeDataSync(): SomethingOrAnother
```

Now, you do not need to observe a `LiveData`. You will need to call `gimmeDataSync()` on a background thread, though.

Or, since you are using Kotlin, you could add the Room dependency for coroutine support, and have:

```
@Query("...")
suspend fun gimmeDataAsync(): SomethingOrAnother
```

Once again, you do not need to observe a `LiveData`. You will need to call `gimmeDataAsync()` from inside of a coroutine, such as using `viewModelScope` on a `ViewModel`:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
  val something = dao.gimmeDataAsync()
  // TODO do something with something
}
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know if this works, thank you

Comment: This still doesn't work. I've updated my question with some codes above. Please help me.

Comment: @MervinHemaraju: That cannot return `null`, as `goals_NotLive` is not nullable.

Comment: It's not returning null, it's returning size 0. Changed my question, sorry

Comment: @MervinHemaraju: `launch()` is asynchronous with respect to the caller. `getGoals()` calls `getGoalsNotLive()`, which returns immediately. Your `launch()` block is not executing yet, let alone your `IO` block. So, your `var` is still an empty list. Get rid of the `var`. Get rid of `getGoals()`. Use the result of `database.goalDao.getAllGoals_NotLive()` in the viewmodel. Do it in the `IO` block if you need to do background work (e.g., save the data to disk). Do it in the `launch` block if you need to do the work on the main application thread.

Comment: Works like a charm after i modified it as per your advices! Thank you so much!

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm getting suggestion Redundant 'suspend' modifier . Also when i changed database row via Database inspector, values are not updating in UI.

Comment: @AskQ: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, with your own [mcve] showing your code that is giving you these results.